# Infinite list: after "Go back" to the list, the new elements are not there any more. How to restore them?

Tags: jquery, ajax

Im using AJAX to make an infinite list of elements (products). When I go to another web site far from the list, and then "Go back" using the browser to the list page, the products added while scrolling down *are not anymore there..*

My question: after "Go back", **how to show the products again (even those added while scrolling down)?**

I thought in these two options:

Option 1: restore them in some way since they were already shown in the client. In other words, they already are in the user's computer. is this possible???

Option 2: make another AJAX request to restore the products.

This is the kind of AJAX request Im using to get the products while scrolling down:

```
  <a href="{{ path('product1') }}">product 1</a>
  <a href="{{ path('product2') }}">product 2</a>
  <a class="get-products" href="#">Get more products</a>

  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    $('.get-products').on('click',function() {
      event.preventDefault();
      $.ajax({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'http://procom/app_dev.php/get-more-products', 
        success: function(response) {
          $('body').prepend(response);
        }
      }); 
    });
  </script>
```

Comment: If possible , can post `html` , other included `js` , create stacksnippets / jsfiddle to demonstrate ?

Comment: @guest271314 I paste some code more. It is a simple code to start. Just to show a pair or products and make an AJAX call. My question is this: what should I do to show the products again (even those added while scrolling down) after going back?